# How to place PHP function result in particular <div>? I am using AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

I have implemented a dynamic creation of a HTML table using AJAX.

Here's what I've created:

**index.php**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ContactController.js">
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="main-wrapper">

        <div id="menu">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="getAllContacts()">
                Go to contacts
            </a>
        </div>

        <div id="main-content">
        </div>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

**ContactsController.js**

```
function getAllContacts() {

    // Manage new XmlHttpObject creation
    xmlHttp = GetXmlHttpObject();
    if (xmlHttp == null) {
        alert ("Your browser is out of date. Please upgrade.");
        return;
    }

    var url = "getAllContacts.php";

    // Workaround for page caching
    url = url + "?sid=" + Math.round(Math.random() * 1000000000);

    xmlHttp.open("POST", url, true);

    // Manage XmlHttpObject state change
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = stateChanged;

    xmlHttp.send(null);
}

function stateChanged() {

    // Check if the XmlHttp request is complete
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {

        // Set the XmlHttp response in the contacts div
        document.getElementById("main-content").innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;
    }
}

// Creates a new XmlHttpObject
function GetXmlHttpObject() {

    var xmlHttp = null;

    try {
        // XmlHttpObject constructor for Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e) {
        // XmlHttpObject constructor for Internet Explorer > v6.0
        try {
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            // XmlHttpObject constructor for Internet Explorer > v5.5
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
    }
    return xmlHttp;
}
```

**getAllContacts.php**

```
<?php

include 'connectToMySQL.php';

$command = "SELECT * FROM contact";
$result = mysql_query($command);

echo "<table id='contactsTable' border='1'>";

// Table headers
echo "<tr>
          <th>Name</th>
      </tr>";

// Print all contacts
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>
              <a href='#'
                 onclick=\"getContact('" . $row['DisplayName'] . "')\">"
                  . $row['DisplayName'] .
             "</a>
          </td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";

mysql_close();

?>
```

So, clicking on a `Go to contacts` link activates a `getAllContacts` javascript function. That function calls `getAllContacts` php function which retrieves the data from MySQL database and places it in the `contactsTable` table.

What I need is to tell the function to place that table in the `main-content` div located in the `index.php` page. How do I achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried what you have?  What function do you want to tell?  The JS function already knows.

Comment: Also, no need to use the POST method if you're not posting anything.  Change it to this: `xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);`.

Comment: @Joha Bron, what does JS function already know? What if I had multiple divs? How can I determine where the table will be placed?

Comment: @Boris, "what if I had multiple divs?"  You should never have more than one thing on a page with the same ID.  IDs are unique.

Comment: Prototype has an Ajax.Updater function that would work very well here.   I would recommend giving it a try, as the hard work has been done for you.

Comment: Another thing that I would suggest is in the php code.  I would create a variable and build the entire response into that variable, then return that variable all at once at the end of the script, rather than echoing it line by line.

Comment: @Mike Ruhlin: I meant having two different divs, each having different ids. So, if a button is calling a script, how do I determine which div will receive the script result?

Comment: You should really be sending a json object from the server with the id and displayname, then create the html within javascript, and then binding onclick events and passing in the id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, so going from your comment about wanting two different possible target divs, just define your onreadystatechanged event inline and use a local variable to refer to the div...

```
function getAllContacts() {

    // Manage new XmlHttpObject creation
    var xmlHttp = GetXmlHttpObject(); // MAKE THIS LOCAL INSTEAD OF GLOBAL!
    if (xmlHttp == null) {
        alert ("Your browser is out of date. Please upgrade.");
        return;
    }

    var url = "getAllContacts.php";

    // Workaround for page caching
    url = url + "?sid=" + Math.round(Math.random() * 1000000000);

    xmlHttp.open("POST", url, true);

    var targetDiv = document.getElementById(whateverIdYouWant);

    // Manage XmlHttpObject state change
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        // Check if the XmlHttp request is complete
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {

            // Set the XmlHttp response in the contacts div
            targetDiv.innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;
        }
    }

    xmlHttp.send(null);
}
```